# Does AFNetworking 2.6 is compatible with IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, afnetworking-2

I can't use AFNetworking 3.x actually.
Does the 2.6.X version is compatible with IPv6 ? Even Reachability ?

Apple says:

> Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store must support
>   IPv6-only networking. Most apps will not require any changes because
>   IPv6 is already supported by NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs.

I'm not using NSURLSession but NSURLConnection... (waiting a migration of my app to Swift in the next months to use NSURLSession).

Note that I'm using URL with names in my app, not IP.

Thanks,

Comment: I've asked this question here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/3174#issuecomment-217256726

Comment: Do you think we can use the 3.0 version of the Reachability class with AFNetworking 2.x ?

Comment: I have tested creating a NAT64 local network (sharing) - as Apple recommended for tests - and all seems to work in my app.